# how to check and show error if same data exists as array in firestore

Tags: android, arrays, google-cloud-firestore, get

The code which i write  for storing data stores data in firestore as an array .
Problem is
1)if same user enter same name twice it overwrites them
2)if mulpile users enter same name it stores in firestore.

So I want to show error if same name is enter either by same user or multiple users.
How to do this query.please help

for more understanding . let a user with phone number 6458935467 enters name as "beautiful" so second time he enters the same name in the edittext there is no change in firestore . but let another user with phone number 7638956478 enters name as "beautiful" but this time firestore add this name even though previous user already enter this name..
so I want to make user sure that there is no duplicate entries made by them.
I want to check if same name is there in firestore by any of the user and show error before they proceed

below is the method I use to store and update the names in arrays in firestore

mainActivity

```
    private void storeNewUserData() {
        

                //to get user phone number
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                String a = (preferences.getString("phoneNo", ""));
        

                TextInputLayout ig_name;
                ig_name = findViewById(R.id.ig_name);


                String name = Objects.requireNonNull(ig_name.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();
                final Map<String, Object> addUserToArrayMap = new HashMap<>();
                addUserToArrayMap.put("Name", FieldValue.arrayUnion(name));
        

                //updating name of existing array field
                firebaseFirestore
                        .collection("Note")
                        .document(a)
                        .update(addUserToArrayMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> task) -> {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
        
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(error -> {

                        
                           //adding name in firestore as array field if no field exists
                            firebaseFirestore
                                    .collection("Note")
                                    .document(a)
                                    .set(addUserToArrayMap)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
        
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
        
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(e2 ->
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e2));
                            editor.apply();
                        });
            }
```

Comment: I do not understand the problems mentioned. Can you please add little more to it?

Comment: yah kindly check I have added more information

Comment: the code worked fine and I have explained the problem elaboretly ..please kindly help  me with this problem

Comment: Unfortunately from presented code I am not able to understand it. Is there any mechanism that checking if entered value already exist in firestore?